# Apple M1 - Maven Java dependency that is not yet available for macosx-arm64

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, apple-silicon, rosetta-2

I am trying to get a Java/Maven project working on an Apple M1 with a dependency that is not yet available for the M1 chip. In my case this is nd4j but it could be any other dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0-beta7</version>
</dependency>
```

I am using IntelliJ for this project.

I am looking for a way to specify some sort of "compatibility mode" that tells maven/IntelliJ to fetch dependencies for X86 chips and execute Java, the tests, maven, etc. with Rosetta. If that's not possible, what could be other was to solve this?

Comment: Out of interest, do you have a JDK that runs natively on M1 already (or is that still using Rosetta as well)?

Comment: I run the Azul JDK. I installed Maven via homebrew, and I think it contains an experimental OpenJDK with M1 support. My other Java projects work fine with Azul JDK as I don't have the nod4j dependency for these other projects.

Comment: Have you tried with the "normal" OpenJDK? That will still be x86, run via Rosetta, and presumably tell Maven that it's architecture is also x86.

Comment: I just tried this after Mario's answer below. This indeed works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can install both x86_64 based and arm64 based JDKs on your machine, and switch between these as needed. A tool like SDKMAN! can help you with that: [How to install x86 and Arm JDKs on the Mac M1](https://itnext.io/how-to-install-x86-and-arm-jdks-on-the-mac-m1-apple-silicon-using-sdkman-872a5adc050d)

If your maven and IntelliJ use the default JDK, they will automatically switch between x86_64 and Arm64 architecture, when you switch JDKs.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. This does work. One minor downside is that nd4j doesn't seem to work really well with Rosetta, but I guess there is nothing we can do about that. The project builds and is runnable, so this is a huge improvement already. The tests run fine. But when using a bigger neural net, nd4j uses huge amounts of RAM and ends up throwing OOM exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

Just want to update this post: we actually do properly support M1 macs now and have for a while now.
Ensure you do the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-M2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.nd4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>nd4j-native</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-M2.1</version>
  <classifier>macosx-arm64</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
  <artifactId>openblas</artifactId>
  <version>0.3.21-1.5.8</version>
  <classifier>macosx-arm64</classifier>
</dependency>
```

We do not provide support for this in the normal nd4j-native-platform. That is due to the scope of dependencies not all having mac arm versions but the math library does work out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you use IDEA for Java on Apple, don't use IDEA M1 version, use Intel version. Then maven will use macosx-x86 jar. Just change JDK is not helpful to me.

Comment: Also need to switch x86_64 JDKs, because maven detect os.arch use JDKs